# Unexpected STR_TO_DATE return value when using with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, rhel

My Transaction MySQL database is Hosted in Centos 7. I am getting the following output of the query with jdbc:

SELECT a.party_code,CAST(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(a.bill_month,'%y%m'),'%M-%Y') AS CHAR) AS bill_month_word,a.bill_month,a.bill_amt,a.rebate,DATE_FORMAT(a.due_date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS due_dt,DATE_FORMAT(a.bill_date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS bill_date,b.name FROM v_bill_info a,consdb.v_party_info b WHERE a.party_code='230728' AND  a.party_code=b.party_code AND a.due_date>=CURDATE() AND a.bill_month NOT IN (SELECT a.bill_month FROM v_bill_info a,TRANSACTION b WHERE b.consumer_no='230728' AND b.consumer_no=a.party_code AND DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(a.bill_month,'%y%m'),'%Y-%m')=DATE_FORMAT(b.bill_month,'%Y-%m') AND b.billdesk_status='0300' ) ORDER BY due_date LIMIT 1

output is -
"party_code"    "bill_month_word"   "bill_month"    "bill_amt"  "rebate"    "due_dt"    "bill_date" "name"
"230728"    "April-2017"    "1704"  "1272"  "26"    "30-05-2017"    "18-05-2017"    "SRI KARTICK CHANDRA DAS "

But when executing the same query from the MIS database hosted in RHEL 7 i am getting a null value for column bill_month_word. But the query returns proper result i.e "April-2017" when executed from query editor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was associated with "Invalid Token" associated with MySQL in Red Hat Linux 7.

The following line requires to be added in /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
sql-mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES"

restart the mysqld service.

what it does is it lets JDBC extract the computed date value based on apparently invalid date value passed to str_to_date() function.